# myslq- php calculate total hours into new column in table

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to calculate the total hour, i insert the start hour and then i update the end hour of the id:

```
UPDATE worked_hours
set End= '$end'
WHERE Id= '$id'
```

So just before the end hour is updated i want to calculate the total hour in all table records.  (end - start = total). Thanks i will aprecciate some help with this and also i hope i was clear with my question.

```
ID | Worker |  Start  |   End    | Total  |
1  |  Jhon  |11:25:40 | 14:04:53 |2:39:31 |
2  |  pete  |10:26:00 | 14:04:53 |3:40:53 |
3  |  David |11:35:30 | 19:04:38 |7:29:08 |
```

Comment: try getting the difference with the TIMEDIFF function, test out the expression in a SELECT  statement:   `SELECT TIMEDIFF(t.end,t.start), t.end, t.start FROM mytable t`

Comment: If we've got an expression that returns the difference we want to assign to a column, then we can use that in an UPDATE statement.  `UPDATE mytable t SET t.total = TIMEDIFF(t.end,t.start)`.  (I would *test* the expression in a SELECT statement before using it in an UPDATE statement.)

Comment: thanks it works on workbench, but where can i add this update statement, after the "UPDATE end hour" statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the suggestion by @spencer7593 in a comment [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) will accomplish the calculation.

Query:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('14:04:53', '11:25:40');
```

Result:

```
02:39:13
```

On the PHP update query side, you can update the total at the same time as the End time by using:

```
$query = "UPDATE `worked_hours` AS wh
SET `wh`.`End` = '$End',
    `wh`.`Total` = TIMEDIFF('$End', `wh`.`Start`)
WHERE `wh`.`ID` = '$ID'";
```

---

I also highly recommend that you utilize [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
$query = 'UPDATE `worked_hours` AS wh
SET `wh`.`End` = ?,
    `wh`.`Total` = TIMEDIFF(?, `wh`.`Start`)
WHERE `wh`.`ID` = ?'

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($End, $End, $ID));
```